# grep and command-line variable substitution

Tags: shell-script, quoting

In the following command sequence,

```
 $ grep -E '^.{11,22}John' emplist 
 Operations John Thompson  PARTHawks        Cher           
 Sales      John Jacobs    FULLHawks        Davinder Singh 
 Finance    Dean Johnson   FULLVegans       Sandeep Jain   
 $ Name=John
 $ grep -E '^.{11,22}$Name' emplist 
 $
```

I want the output of

```
grep -E '^.{11,22}$Name' emplist
```

to be the same as the output of

```
grep -E '^.{11,22}John' emplist
```

Comment: See the [Bash Wiki on quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)...

Answer (score 3):

```
Name=John
grep -E "^.{11,22}$Name" emplist
```